# Module name in SOAP requests, how to get rid of them?

Tags: php, soap, web-services, symfony1

When I generate a WSDL file with ./symfony webservice:generate-wsdl    (where  is 'frontend',  is 'soap' and  is 'http://localhost ') I get a nice soap.wsdl file which works like it should. Except, the methods are not named 'justAMethod' but 'soapService_justAMethod' (where soapService is the module which holds the SOAP methods). How do I omit the module name in the SOAP method names? I know this is possible since the previous release of the software had no module name in the SOAP method names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: the option '-h' on './symfony webservice:generate-wsdl' creates a custom soapHandler, effectively omitting the module name in the SOAP methods. This is not in the documentation however.